# white bar on-top of keyboard on focusing TextInput :React Native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, whitespace, textinput, keyboardavoidingview

So, in a component, When focusing an input field, a white background appears behind the keyboard, it extends up to 20-30px above the keyboard, it is like, a white bar is sitting above the keyboard.
sometimes it will open normal, sometimes the bar takes the same size of the keyboard, above it

you can see in the attached pic[White bar on top of Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXWuf.jpg)

i thought there is bottom padding, flex/layout issues, ,keyboardAvoidingView problem etc etc trial and error,
expecting keyboard opens normally,but nothing solved

Comment: Are you using safe area containers? It can be happening because of bottom padding from safe area container. 
You should share a code snippet of the component structure for better explanation.

Answer (score -1):

while using Statusbar of React native, this issue is rising,
specifically the translucent prop of the Status bar, on commenting out the translucent prop the issue is solved for me.
Even though i checked them , im not sure if the combination of things ,like KeyboardAvoidingView+StatusBar or scrollview + StatusBar + KeyboardAvoidingView is causing the issue

for now , this worked for me(better remove the whole thing)

```js
<StatusBar
  barStyle="light-content"
  //translucent={true} <-----------------
  backgroundColor="#000"
 />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).